# What is the function of the plot map system in Deponia?

Tags: deponia

In Deponia, there's a... hint? system that gets gradually revealed as the player progresses through the game, with cartoon versions of plot points connected flowchart-style.  As I play, certain paths get crossed out.  Sometimes if I hover over an image, text appears explaining it, but sometimes not.  I'm uncertain what the function of this chart is--is it telling me that I made choices that affected the flow of the game?  If I replay the game, can I change the outcome?  For example, in the diagram below there's an arrow leading from the suitcase (very early in the game) to Elysium (the end of the game) that is crossed out.  Could I have done something different to end the game right away?

[image]

Comment: Which Deponia is this? I don't recall seeing this in the first game

Comment: @Sentry It is part of at least the first two games (I haven't played the third yet, but I assume it's there).  The screenshot is from the first game--you can recognize plot points such as making the espresso just below center on the left and packing the suitcase in the upper left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First of all, I will assume you're talking about Deponia 2.</strike> Deponia 1 is linear; there are no alternate endings. However, there are many missable achievements. Overall this 'map' is meant as an impromptu 'todo' list for Rufus. It changes for every chapter in the game, and serves no purpose other than to alert you to locations/actions/etc that exist in each level.

This 'map' has very little impact most of the time, and should serve more as a journal. I know I often ask myself "did I miss something?" when playing these sorts of games. This feature is meant to allow you feedback so you don't get lost in between play sessions.

Comment: The screenshot above is from the first Deponia, although there are similar features in all 3.  I don't understand how/why some paths get x'ed out.  There's a path with a red 'X' leading from packing the suitcase (one of the first Rufus tasks) directly to Elysium.  How could I have taken that route?

Comment: paths get X'd out as Rufus encounters roadblocks along his journey. There are no alternate paths in Deponia 1- just chapters 1-8. You can not have taken that route

Comment: Ah, so every path (except the pre-destined one) is intended to eventually be crossed out?  What about things like the divining rod in the lower left-hand corner over Wenzel?  It's red

Comment: I believe that is the location you're currently at, however I haven't played in quite awhile- it might be that you 100% the area?